# File saved locally with FileSaver not opening.

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-drive-api, filesaver.js

I'm trying to save a file using FileSaver and "technically" it is working, I say "technically" because the file won't open.

To test it I created a brand new file, uploaded and tried to download, still when I try to open the downloaded file I get:

[image]

I download the file from Google Drive using:

`_service.Files.Export(fileId, type).ExecuteAsStream();`

Then I convert that stream to byte[]:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var stream = StorageService.GetStream(file.StorageId); //invoking previous code

    stream.CopyTo(ms);
    resource.Content = ms.ToArray(); //saves to view model
}
```

My Javascript:

```
download(fileId: string): void {
  this.fileStore.download(fileId).then(function (file: StorageFile) {
    if (file) {
      let data = new Blob([file.content], { type: file.type });
      fileSaver.saveAs(data, file.title);
    }
  });
}
```

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to the byte array (string) decoding. It was base64. So after decoding it I was able to get it working.

Taken from SO:

```
let byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
let byteArrays = [];

for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
  let slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
  let byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  let byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

  byteArrays.push(byteArray);
}

let blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
```